# Find the integral of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{x^2 + a^2} dx$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Note: this maybe of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

**Question**: Find the integral of $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{x^2 + a^2} dx$$

The correct solution is $\dfrac{1}{b} (\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{x}{a}) + \dfrac{\pi}{2})$ but I couldn't get this answer after a few attempts:

---

**Attempts:**

\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{x^2 + a^2} dx  &= \dfrac{1}{ab}\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{1}{(\dfrac{x}{a})^2 + 1} dx 
\end{align*}

Let $y = \dfrac{x}{a}$, then $ady =dx$, continuing on:

\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{x^2 + a^2} dx  &= \dfrac{1}{ab}\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \dfrac{1}{(\dfrac{x}{a})^2 + 1} dx \\& = \dfrac{1}{b}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{ay} \dfrac{1}{y^2 + 1} dy
\\& = \dfrac{1}{b}(\tan^{-1} (ay) - \tan^{-1}(-\infty)) \\& = \dfrac{1}{b}(\tan^{-1} (ay) + \tan^{-1}(\infty)) \\ &= \dfrac{1}{b}(\tan^{-1}(x) + \dfrac{\pi}{2}) 
\end{align*}

I haven't done this in a while. Where did I go wrong in my steps?

Comment: You are simply bitten back by the fact that you use the same letter for a bound and for the integration letter, leading to the absurd $$\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)dx$$

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just fudging the substitution. Start by not partaking in the bad habit of using the same name for a dummy variable and a free variable. And then don't act like $y$ is something you can be left with after the integral is over... $x$ is your free variable. Perhaps you are confused here cause the some people are taught to do *indefinite* integrations with substitutions kind of looks like this at the end.

So you want the substitution to look like $$ \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{(t/a)^2+1}dt = a\int_{-\infty}^{x/a}\frac{1}{u^2+1}du$$ and pick it up from there.

Comment: Ok, now I remember